# A Thought on Recursive Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In working on coursework I had a thought about recursive sequences.  For monotone. bounded, recursive sequences $(x_n)$ , $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)$ seems to equal the point where the differences in terms is zero (i.e. $x_n-x_{n+1}=0$).  On brief consideration it seems to stand to reason - the term difference is essentially the rate of change of the sequence, a monotone sequence must be changing in the same direction for all terms.   Thus, the sequence should tend toward the point where the next term *would* be larger if the sequence got there, but never quite actually get there.  Hence, the limit.

I would like to ask: is this a known result?  If so, does the theorem have a name?  If not, where can one poke holes in the claim?

Comment: As an example, suppose that $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$.  Then, under suitable conditions, the limit of $(x_n)$ is a **fixed point** of the function $F$, that is, a point $a$ such that $F(a)=a$.  That term is standard. I do not know of a specific additional name for the result.

Comment: @andre those are types of sequences that I led me to this thought.  Probably just jumped the gun on something later in the course, but it would be cool if that property had a name. None as far as you know?  Also, what are the suitable conditions?

Comment: It sort of has a name, the fixed point property.  Your conditions (monotone, bounded) together with continuity of $F$ will do it.  We don't really need monotone.  Asking that $F$ be differentiable with $|F'(x)|<c<1$ will do.  The recurrence need not be first-order. For example, $x_{n+1}=F(x_{n},x_{n-1})$ with $F$ nice enough will do. There is a large literature, since the subject is strongly associated with root-finding techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of this type belong to a family of results called **fixed point** theorems.  So you could call it **a** fixed point theorem.  The family of fixed point theorems is so vast and so diverse that, except for local reference in a particular chapter, one could not call it **the** fixed point theorem.

There are many results to the effect that under suitable conditions on $F$, if the sequence $(x_n)$ satisfies a recurrence of the shape $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists and is equal to a solution of the equation $F(x)=x$, or in other words that the limit is a fixed point of $F$.  This is true, for example, if $F$ is differentiable and $|F'(x)|$ is (say) everywhere $<0.9$.

Given the recurrence $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$, where $F$ is continuous, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, **if it exists**, must be a fixed point of $F$. So a common first step in finding the limit is to find the fixed points of $F$. However, we still need to show that the limit exists.  The following is a simple illustrative example. Let $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)=-x_n^2$.  The fixed points of $F$ are $x=0$ and $x=-1$.  If $x_0=1/2$, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a limit, which must be one of the fixed points of $F$.  But we cannot use fixed points to "find" the limit if $x_0=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Monotone bounded sequences of real numbers converge to their sup. This is sometimes called the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).